# My rewrite block on magento 1.9 doesn't work

Tags: php, xml, magento, url-rewriting

Hello I'm newbie in Magento, I tried do rewrite to my block
my script like this:
app/etc/modules/Lesson2_all.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lesson2_Test>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends><Mage_Catalog /></depends>
        </Lesson2_Test>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/local/Lesson2/Test/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        ...
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       ...
    </frontend>
    <global>
      <blocks>
          <catalog>
              <rewrite>
                  <product_view>Lesson2_Test_Block_Catalog_Product_View</product_view>
              </rewrite>
          </catalog>
          <lesson2>
              <class>Lesson2_Test_Block</class>
          </lesson2>
      </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/local/Lesson2/Test/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Lesson2_Test_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
   }

    public function testAction()
    {
        echo 'test mymethod';
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Lesson2/Test/Block/Monblock.php (my default block)

```
<?php
class Lesson2_Test_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
     public function methodblock()
     {
         return 'informations about my block !!' ;
     }
}
```

Is it possible this error was in my new block? Is it true rewrite of models/resource can only be summoned by Mage `such as Mage:: getModel (), Mage:: getResourceModel (), Mage:: Helper (), Mage:: getSingletonBlock ()` ?

app/code/local/Lesson2/Test/BLock/Catalog/Product/View.php

```
<?php
class Lesson2_Test_Block_Catalog_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{
    public function productView()
    {
        return 'skuycesiu';
    }
}
```

And I have layout and template on:
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/lesson2.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <default>
      <reference name="content">
      </reference>
  </default>
  <lesson2_index_index>
       <reference name="content">
            <block type="lesson2/monblock" name="afficher_monbloc" template="lesson2/afficher.phtml" />
       </reference>
  </lesson2_index_index>
</layout>
```

app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/lesson2/afficher.phtml

```
<?php    
    echo $this->methodblock();
?>
```

If  I run this script localhost/magento/lesson2 , I doesn't look something happens, I just see a message: "informations about my block !!" (this is my default block) 
Thank you, sorry if I understand this wrong.

Comment: If you go to `localhost/magento/lesson2/index/index` does it work? Also, please share the code where you have `...` inside `<modules>` in config.xml, because that should not be in that file

Comment: Also, `app/etc/modules/Lesson2_all.xml` should match your module name, e.g. `app/etc/modules/Lesson2_Test.xml`

Comment: thanks @RobbieAverill
yes still doesn't work, and this my code inside <modules> in config.xml
`<modules>
        <Lesson2_Test>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Lesson2_Test>
     </modules>`
status Lesson2_Test on modules output at system->advanced is enabled

Comment: this is my code inside <frontend>
`     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <lesson2>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Lesson2_Test</module>
                 <frontName>lesson2</frontName>
              </args>
           </lesson2>
       </routers>
       <layout>
         <updates>
              <lesson2>
                   <file>lesson2.xml</file>
               </lesson2>
          </updates>
      </layout>
    </frontend>`

Comment: is it possible his error was in my new block? is it true rewrite of models/resource can only be summoned by Mage `such as Mage:: getModel (), Mage:: getResourceModel (), Mage:: Helper (), Mage:: getSingletonBlock ()` ?